# JsonConvert.SerializeObject() causing JSON to be malformed

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` is causing me to have malformed JSON strings. I start off with object to be serialised as follows:

```
public List<AccountTypeObject> Creator()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 11; ++j)
        {
            if ((i % 2) == 0)
            {
                AllTransactionsList.Add(new SingleTransactionObject(j + 101 + j,
                    "I'am putting in money right now", "1500" + j, "0",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                AllTransactionsList.Add(new SingleTransactionObject(j + 101 + j,
                    "I need money right now", "500" + j, "0",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            }
        }

        AllAccountTypesList.Add(new AccountTypeObject(i + "55" + i + "632" + i,
            i + "MACMONSAM NICOLAS", +i + "100,000.00", AllTransactionsList));
    }

    return AllAccountTypesList;
}
```

When I apply  this code:

```
// GET api/uconnectservice
public String Get()
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        operations = sampledata.GetAllDummy(),
    });

    return json;
}
```

Once I run this service I get this JSON string:

```
"{\"operations\":[{\"AccountType\":\"15516321\",\"CustomerName\":\"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"1100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"}]},{\"AccountType\":\"25526322\",\"CustomerName\":\"2MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"2100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"}]},{\"AccountType\":\"35536323\",\"CustomerName\":\"3MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"3100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"}]}]}"
```

However when I go to [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/) I'm told there is string parse error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like you just copied the `string` with escaped quotes straight out of IDE. Those quotes won't be escaped in normal use.

Comment: The string literal contains valid json according to that curiousconcept.com site, assuming you treat it like a **C# string literal**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed you have \" in your json string, is not quite a json string this is why you get the string parse error, you need to remove all \, also remove the starting ending " (they were added by Visual studio when you watched the json content I assume right?, cause your serialization is ok, there is nothing wrong with it).
I did this and got the following:

```
{"operations":[{"AccountType":"15516321","CustomerName":"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"1100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"}]},{"AccountType":"25526322","CustomerName":"2MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"2100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"}]},{"AccountType":"35536323","CustomerName":"3MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"3100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 11:40:24"}]}]}
```

Change your method to :

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(sampledata.GetAllDummy());
    }
```

You don't have to do any json serialization, the framework will do it for you.

Comment: thxs however i have to send this data to Android app.How can i remove these slashes from the server side so as to send only JSON data to client app?

Comment: **How** do you verify that the backslashes are present? What people are talking about here is that if you're using the debugger, quick-watch or similar to display the content of that string, **that** system escapes the string, but the string itself does not actually contain those backslashes. In other words, this is a "problem" due to how you obtained the string, not a problem **with** the string. Please tell us how you obtained that json.

Comment: You don't need to remove them, because they aren't there when getting to the Android client, you only see them because is the way the C# displays the string. Your json is valid actually at client's end.

Comment: Not the way **C#** displays the string, but the way **the debugger** displays the string.

Comment: @Lasse i got the Json while using JsonConvert.SerializeObject() (see code above)

Comment: @Andrei almost got but a part of the JSON has been cut off in the client(Android app), i don't know why i will keep looking,thanks for the help you guys provided

Answer (score 0):

You json is valid you need to use `JSON.parse` to convert data to `json object`

```
var data = "{\"operations\":[{\"AccountType\":\"15516321\",\"CustomerName\":\"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"1100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"}]},{\"AccountType\":\"25526322\",\"CustomerName\":\"2MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"2100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"}]},{\"AccountType\":\"35536323\",\"CustomerName\":\"3MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"3100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\",\"ValueDate\":\"15/12/2016 11:40:24\"}]}]}";

 var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is the C# Debug or Watch output for a string, surrounded by `""` and with all the internal `"` escaped as `\"`.

It seems that you fed this *as-is* into both parsers, with the result that they say it is invalid, and it sure is. After I undid the escaping and removed the surrounding quotes, and fed that into both parsers, then everything passed with flying colors. So the lesson is, be careful with using Debug or Watch output.